# Not seeing AddonPreferences after registering

Tags: python, scripting, export, add-on, customization

I'm sure I am just doing something stupid here, but whenever I create an addon preferences class and register it, I am not seeing it appear in `bpy.context.preferences.addons`.
Furthermore, In the examples I see in the documentation, it appears that for addon preferences I am supposed to assign `__name__` to the preference class' `bl_idname` but throughout execution, I never see `__name__` being anything other than `"__main__"`, which I would expect if the goal was to name the id after the script or package. As a result, I keep running into the following error when I run my script.

> `Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/sigs/blender/pugin-dev.blend/SIGExport.py", line 50, in execute KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "__main__" not found'`

here is my code:

```
import bpy;
import bpy_extras;

from bpy.types import AddonPreferences;
from bpy.types import Operator;
from bpy.types import Panel;
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper;

bl_info = {
    "name":"SIGExport",
    "author":"sigs",
    "version": {1, 0},
    "blender": {3, 21, 0},
    "location": "View3D -> Export Mesh",
    "category": "Mesh Export",
};
#bl_info = {};
#bl_info["name"] = "SIGExport";
#bl_info["author"] = "sigs";
#bl_info["version"] = {1, 0};
#bl_info["blender"] = {3, 21, 0};
#bl_info["location"] = "View3D -> Export Mesh";
#bl_info["warning"] = "";
#bl_info["wiki_url"] = "";
#bl_info["category"] = "Mesh Export";

class SIGExportPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__;
    export_path : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        subtype="FILE_PATH",
        default="out.sig"
    );
    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row();
        row.prop(self, "export_path");
        return;

class SIGExportFilePrompt(Operator, ExportHelper):
    bl_idname = "sigexport.prompt_export_file";
    bl_label = "Select Export File";
    release_confirm = False;
    filter_glob : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        default="*.sig",
        options={"HIDDEN"}
    );
    filename_ext = ".sig"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print("__name__:"+__name__);
        prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences;
        prefs.export_path = self.filepath;
        print("export_path:"+export_path);
        return {"FINISHED"};

class SIGExportPanel(Panel):
    bl_label = "Export SIG";
    bl_idname = "SIGEXPORT_PT_TOOL_PANEL";
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D';
    bl_region_type = 'UI';
    bl_category = "Export Mesh";
    
    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row();
        row.operator("sigexport.prompt_export_file", text="", icon="FILE_FOLDER");
        return;

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SIGExportPanel);
    bpy.utils.register_class(SIGExportFilePrompt);
    bpy.utils.register_class(SIGExportPreferences);
    
    return;

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SIGExportPanel);
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SIGExportFilePrompt);
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SIGExportPreferences);
    return;

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register();
```

Comment: try changing "blender": {3, 21, 0}, to 3,2,0

Comment: @Chris okay... I'm still seeing the same error. I also tried it in 2.8 and saw the same thing

Comment: `bl_idname = __package__` is correct.  `__name__` only works if the addon is a single file that is given the package name.  If you have an `__init__.py` file then you need `__package__`.  The documentation is unclear.

Comment: @Marty Fouts i did see something about that. This addon is (so far) only one file, I did try  `__package__` anyways just for the heck of it, and that didnt work either

Comment: I just noticed that you're using curly brackets for "version" and "blender", but they are supposed to be tuples. Switch those to parenthesis.

Comment: @MartyFouts okay, i changed that, and im still seeing the same thing

Comment: You have several problems, but the main one is this:  If you install your addon from `FILE.py` the `bl_idname = "FILE"` works and your preferences are drawn.

Comment: @MartyFouts the main problem (as i said below) turned out to be that the code only works when installed, and not when debugging it as a script

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that comment.  Yes, when running from the text editor, `__main__` doesn't have a file name to use.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, the documentation is a bit obscure.  There are two ways to prepare an addon for installation and they require different settings for the preference class `bl_idname` variable:

1. You install from a single python file: `bl_idname = __name__`
2. You install from a zip file:

   1. Your initialization code must be in a file named '__init__.py'.
   2. `bl_idname = __package__`

But you have a few other problems with your addon, and they were obscuring the correct answer for `bl_idname`.  Here's an edited version that solves all but one of those problems:

```py
bl_info = {
    "name":"SIGExport",
    "description": "SIG Exporter",
    "author": "sigs",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 2, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Export Mesh",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "category": "Import-Export",
};


import bpy;
import bpy_extras;

from bpy.types import AddonPreferences;
from bpy.types import Operator;
from bpy.types import Panel;
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper;

class SIGExportPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__;
    export_path : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        subtype="FILE_PATH",
        default="out.sig"
    );
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(self, "export_path");
        return;

class SIGExport_OT_FilePrompt(Operator, ExportHelper):
    bl_idname = "sigexport.prompt_export_file";
    bl_label = "Select Export File";
    release_confirm = False;
    filter_glob : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        default="*.sig",
        options={"HIDDEN"}
    );
    filename_ext = ".sig"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print("__name__:"+__name__);
        prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences;
        prefs.export_path = self.filepath;
        print("export_path:"+export_path);
        return {"FINISHED"};

class SIGExport_PT_Panel(Panel):
    bl_label = "Export SIG";
    bl_idname = "SIGEXPORT_PT_TOOL_PANEL";
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D';
    bl_region_type = 'UI';
    bl_category = "Export Mesh";
    
    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row();
        row.operator("sigexport.prompt_export_file", text="", icon="FILE_FOLDER");
        return;

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SIGExport_PT_Panel);
    bpy.utils.register_class(SIGExport_OT_FilePrompt);
    bpy.utils.register_class(SIGExportPreferences);
    
    return;

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SIGExport_PT_Panel);
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SIGExport_OT_FilePrompt);
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SIGExportPreferences);
    return;

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register();
```

- `bl_info` should be before any of the imports. (Convention)
- I added a description to `bl_info`.  Not really a problem but see the [Addons Guideline](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Addons/Guidelines/metainfo)
- Also see the Guideline for categories.
- There's a naming convention for addons, introduces in 2.80. I applied it to your operator and panel classes.

**Edit** As the OP pointed out, the main problem was

> that the code only works when installed, and not when debugging it as a script

`__name__` isn't set when you run from a script.

Answer (score 0):

Make an addon folder and put `__init__.py` inside and zip the folder then install it.

```
Addon
|
|-->  __init__.py
```

```py
bl_info = {
    'name': 'SIGExport',
    'author': 'sigs',
    'description': '',
    'blender': (3, 2, 0),
    'version': (1, 0, 0),
    'category': 'Import-Export',
    'location': 'View3D -> Export Mesh',
    'support': 'COMMUNITY',
    'warning': '',
    'doc_url': '',
    'tracker_url': ''
}


import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, Operator, AddonPreferences
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper


class SIGExportFilePrompt(Operator, ExportHelper):

    bl_idname = 'sigexport.prompt_export_file'
    bl_label = 'Select Export File'

    release_confirm = False

    filter_glob : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        default='*.sig',
        options={'HIDDEN'}
    )

    filename_ext = '.sig'
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print(f'__name__:{__name__}')
        prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
        prefs.export_path = self.filepath
        print(f'export_path:{export_path}')
        return {'FINISHED'}


class SIGExportPanel(Panel):

    bl_label = 'Export SIG'
    bl_idname = 'SIGEXPORT_PT_TOOL_PANEL'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Export Mesh'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('sigexport.prompt_export_file', text='', icon='FILE_FOLDER')


class SIGExportPreferences(AddonPreferences):

    bl_idname = __package__

    export_path : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        subtype='FILE_PATH',
        default='out.sig'
    )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self, 'export_path')


classes = (
    SIGExportFilePrompt,
    SIGExportPanel,
    SIGExportPreferences,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
```

Comment: I see nothing when running this. I got some errors after zipping it and installing it as a plugin. after fixing those errors in the code i do see the correct name showing up for `__package__` so it seems like the issue is not the code changes above, but how im loading it

Comment: Make an addon folder and put `__init__.py` inside and zip the folder then install it